# Print multiple child's return value after joining multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

What my program is essentially supposed to do is that it takes multiple command line arguments and creates a thread for each of them. Each thread is assigned to a primeFactors function that returns a pointer to the values of the primefactors.

```
 void *primeFactors(void *param)
 {
      int* p_a = malloc((1000) * sizeof p_a[0]); //arbitrary size, will scale better later
      int number = atoi(param);
      ..... prime factor part .......
      p_a[j] = 0; //sentinel value
      pthread_exit(p_a);
 }
```

I've checked and this does, in fact, return a pointer that points to all the right prime factors. My main function looks like this

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
      int count = 2; //arbitrary 2 just for the purpose of testing 2 arguments
      pthread_t = malloc(count * sizeof(pthread_t));
      pthread_attr_t attr;
      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
           pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, primeFactors, argv[i+1]);
      }
      int j;
      void *prime_array;
      int *p;
      for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
      {
           pthread_join(tid[i], &prime_array);
           p = prime_array;
           int n = 0;
           while (p[n] != 0)
           {
                 printf("%d ", p[n]);
                 n++;
           }
           printf("\n");
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

I've checked this program with only a single command line argument and without the for loop around the pthread_join code and the program works.  The problem seems to arise when I join multiple threads and print the return value array of each thread.  When I run through it with two command line arguments like I have been I get a huge list of numbers as if I ran a random number generator instead of finding prime factors.  I think the error might be something small so I'd appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the full code it is not possible to pinpoint the exact problem(s) causing you grief, however here goes -

Obvious error -

1. `pthread_join(tid[i], &prime_array);` should be
      `pthread_join(tid[j], &prime_array); /* Jay instead of Eye. */`

Suggestions -

1. Instead of `for (i = 0; i < count; i++)`
      use `for (i = 0; i < (argc - 1); i++) /* Use 'argc' instead of the arbitrary 'count'  */`.
    Or, set `int count = argc - 1`.
2. Check return value of functions used (malloc, pthread_xxx()).
    Had you done that you would have probably noticed that pthread_join() returned an error value.

Comment: Sadly the obvious error that you pointed out was exactly the reason why I was getting errors.  Purely oversight on my part.  Also your later suggestions are great. Thank you so much for saving me from a stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Each thread seems to be allocating its own prime_array; I don't see it trying to communicate its address back to the parent.

You might try having the parent allocate the space for each thread's prime_array & pass its address as an argument.